# Selenium 'browserName was not a boolean' InvalidArgumentException, unable to solve

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I'm facing a problem making automatic tests with Selenium on Firefox.
My configuration is the following:

- OS:          Windows 7
- Browser:     Firefox 53.0.3 (tried both x32 and x64 versions)
- Selenium:    3.4.0
- Geckodriver: 0.16.1

Running the following code

```
DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
dc.setCapability("browserName", DesiredCapabilities.firefox().getBrowserName());
dc.setCapability("browserVersion", "");
dc.setCapability("platformName", "WINDOWS");
dc.setCapability("firefox_binary", "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
dc.setCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true);
dc.setCapability("marionette", true);

System.out.println("BrowserName : " + dc.getCapability("browserName"));

driver = new FirefoxDriver(dc);
```

I systematically get the following exception

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: browserName was not a boolean
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: '<ComputerName>', ip: '<IpAddress>', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
remote stacktrace: stack backtrace:
   0:   0x47f1a6 - <no info>
   1:   0x437327 - <no info>
   2:   0x42bd8c - <no info>
   3:   0x437ded - <no info>
   4:   0x41a7b3 - <no info>
   5:   0x40570c - <no info>
   6:   0x692906 - <no info>
   7:   0x413838 - <no info>
   8:   0x68d401 - <no info>
   9: 0x7573336a - BaseThreadInitThunk
  10: 0x774b9902 - RtlInitializeExceptionChain
```

Looking at the Mozilla source code, I found that raised exception should derive from the following file

```
gecko-dev-master\third_party\rust\webdriver\src\capabilities.rs
```

in these lines

```
        for (key, value) in capabilities.iter() {
        match &**key {
            "acceptInsecureCerts" => if !value.is_boolean() {
                    return Err(WebDriverError::new(ErrorStatus::InvalidArgument,
                                                   "acceptInsecureCerts was not a boolean"))
                },
            x @ "browserName" |
            x @ "browserVersion" |
            x @ "platformName" => if !value.is_string() {
                    return Err(WebDriverError::new(ErrorStatus::InvalidArgument,
                                                   format!("{} was not a boolean", x)))
                },
```

To be sure that browserName capability was correctly set, I added the println before creating the FirefoxDriver object.
As stated before, I tried the code with both Firefox 32 bits and 64 bits versions without any different result.

Whereas Chrome and chromedriver work fine.

May any of you suggest how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance and best regards.

Comment: You are hard coding all the other strings, have you tried hard coding this one and see if it works? What line is the exception on?

Comment: Yes, I also tried to hardcode the string before trying the solution I reported in my post.
I added the println to check if the capability was set correctly and I always got 'firefox', but when I instantiate the driver and geckodriver starts, the exception raises.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this in the end? The "answer" to this question doesn't really seem to offer a solution. Like you, I've tried setting the desired capabilities and changing the browser binary but I've had no luck.

Comment: As stated in my answer on Jun 13, I found a solution using Firefox ESR without geckodriver (that should be not working according to documentation...). After that solution I changed my activity and I haven't made any other test till now...

Answer (score 0):

Set the browser name to "firefox" as lined out in the [official documentation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities).

```
dc.setCapability("browserName", "firefox");
```

Comment: dc.setCapability("browserName", "firefox");
dc.setBrowserName("firefox");
dc.setCapability("browserName", DesiredCapabilities.firefox().getBrowserName());
dc.setBrowserName(DesiredCapabilities.firefox().getBrowserName());

(Sorry but I cannot format previous lines as code...)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

1. I did a small check with your exact code block as follows:

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
   DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
   dc.setCapability("browserName", DesiredCapabilities.firefox().getBrowserName());
   dc.setCapability("browserVersion", "");
   dc.setCapability("platformName", "WINDOWS");
   dc.setCapability("firefox_binary", "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
   dc.setCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true);
   dc.setCapability("marionette", true);

   System.out.println("BrowserName : " + dc.getCapability("browserName"));

   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(dc);
   ```
2. Naturally, I got `SessionNotCreatedException` as follows:

   ```
   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
   Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
   System info: host: 'SmackMe', ip: '1.1.1.1', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
   Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
   remote stacktrace: stack backtrace:
      0:           0x489f6f - <no info>
      1:           0x48ad59 - <no info>
      2:           0x43c325 - <no info>
      3:           0x443f9a - <no info>
      4:           0x41ddb1 - <no info>
      5:           0x4091c7 - <no info>
      6:           0x6bc939 - <no info>
      7:           0x415a19 - <no info>
      8:           0x6b6e43 - <no info>
      9:      0x7f94d8a1842 - BaseThreadInitThunk
   ```

which makes pretty sense to me.

3. The logs indicated the follows:

   ```
   at demo.Q44440580_browsername_not_boolean.main(Q44440580_browsername_not_boolean.java:24)
   ```

which points me to :

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(dc);
```

which says the session was not at all created.

4. When I checked the Capabilities of the `DesiredCapabilities` class in details, I didn't find a place holder for the `browserVersion`.
5. As we were trying to add a `capability` not supported by the `FirefoxDriver` hence the `SessionNotCreatedException` error.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Thanks for Your reply, but it's not clear what I should do...
Do you suggest to avoid to set the browserVersion capability? I tried, but the problem persists.
Anyway, I always receive the InvalidArgumentException with message 'browserName was not a boolean', and I never saw the SessionNotCreatedException as you got.

Comment: @PFencer As per my work over your issue, I am yet to be able to retrieve the `browserVersion` from an on-going Firefox browser session through `WebDriver` implementation. On the other hand as we already mentioned the absolute binary location through `firefox_binary` the `browserVersion` is already known to you. So there must be a valid Business Case to retrive the `browserVersion` again. Now, as per your comment `InvalidArgumentException`, try to upgrade your Mozilla Firefox Browser to a stable GA version like 53.0. Let me know if we are on the same page. Thanks

Comment: @PFencer You may consider to avoid setting the `browserVersion` capability till we find a solution. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but as stated in first comment, removing the set of browserVersion didn't change the behaviour of test. As you may see in code that you tried, I added a println to check the browserName capability to be sure of its value and output always displays 'firefox', but when I make the new of FirefoxDriver the exception raises...

Comment: I fail to understand why you are getting `browserName was not a boolean` !!! Whats you Mozilla Firefox Browser version? Thanks

Comment: Can you consider downgrading your Mozilla Firefox Browser to a stable GA version like 53.0? Thanks

Comment: Tried to downgrade, without success. Even for me it's difficult to understand, because, if the capability is set, that particular exception should not raise. Anyway the problem should reside in geckodriver executable because when, instantiating FirefoxDriver, and the executable is launched, the exception raises before any browser window is opened. In case I bypass geckodriver setting marionette to false I got an UnreachableBrowserException (and this should be correct as stated by Selenium and geckodriver documentation)

Answer (score 0):

After some different tries, I discovered that the system works using Firefox ESR version (actually 52.1.2) setting the marionette capability to FALSE.
In this way, geckodriver is bypassed and Firefox browser starts and execute automatic tests.
But at this time, I don't understand how this is possible, due to the fact that, from Firefox 47, geckodriver should be mandatory.
Any suggestion or comment?

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I spent the whole day to solve it.
Maybe just like me you had some **com.google.code.gson** version conflict. Try to use the last version of this artifact.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```